# Compilation errors in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for a QT-based project

Tags: gcc, ld

When running make, the following errors appear in terminal:
//usr/local/lib/liblua.a(loadlib.o) : In function « lookforfunc » :
loadlib.c:(.text+0x576): warning : Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld : cannot find -lQt5Widgets
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld : cannot find -lQt5Gui
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld : cannot find -lQt5Core
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld : cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding these entries in the projects ".pro" file and then generating again the Makefile with qmake. 
The entries are: 
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -no-pie 
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -no-pie 
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie -fPIC 
LIBS += -llua -ldl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Answer (score 0):

I did search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=Qt5Widgets).

According to it you need the following packages:

- for compilation:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
  ```
- at run time:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5core5a libgl1
  ```

Comment: well, I have found the libs, I have copied libQt5Widgets.so and others from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/lib but the errors still appear.

Comment: You should not copy anything from anywhere to the places maintained by package manager ([APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)))!!! With such actions you can trash and mess your system!!! If you want to copy some lib, copy it to the folder folder with your compiled binary.

Comment: sorry, I'm kinda eager to solve this... lol